# How to get string (word) after a character?

Tags: sql

How can I get the first word in a collumn after a character?
with the query below

```
select 
   right(member_name, len(member_name) - charindex(' ', member_name)) as first_name,
   left(member_name, charindex('/', member_name) - 1) + ' ' as last_name
from
   member
```

Im getting the correct last_name but for the first name I'm getting the full name
and I would only like to get the first word after the '/' character.

In the table the collumn has names like 'smith/john doe'
so I would like it to output john (first name ) smith (last_name)

I made a simple http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c7a74/32

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a better solution - check if member has a middle name:

```
select 
 case
  when charindex(' ', member_name) > 0 then
  SUBSTRING(member_name, charindex('/', member_name) + 1, charindex(' ', member_name) - charindex('/', member_name))  
  when charindex(' ', member_name) < 1 then
    SUBSTRING(member_name, charindex('/', member_name) + 1, len(member_name) - charindex('/', member_name))  
end as FIRST_NAME, 
  left(member_name, charindex('/', member_name) - 1) + ' ' as last_name
from
  member
```

I have updated the sql fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/591fb/1)

Comment: this would get you the full first name

Comment: I mean yours output the full first name , and i would only like the first name word

Comment: weird , so when i run this on on my server i get 'Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function'

Comment: I suspect that some of your data is different than in the fiddle. It may not have a space in it. In which case the sql would not work.

Comment: yup just research that error, some data do have names like smith/john-doe

Comment: or like 'smith/MACUMBA-john L ;

Comment: You will need a case statement to handle all the various combinations - see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/591fb/1

Comment: uhh gotta change the last_name too, since i got data like 'MADSnn too REVOC LVG TRST/THE'